# Filtering by multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to filter based on two columns (1 & 2), with different conditions of Col. 2 depending of the condition of Col. 1. For example

df =

```
|Column 1|Column 2|Column 3|
|   A    | 0.578  |   13   |
|   A    | 0.596  |   12   |
|   B    | 0.672  |   33   |
|   B    | 0.333  |   48   |
|   C    | 0.254  |   25   |
|   C    | 0.265  |   33   |
```

Let's say  I want to create a new dataframe with all rows where Column 1 == A *and* Column 2 >= 0.56 **or** Column 1 == B *and* Column 2 => 0.38 **or** Column 1 == C *and* Column 2 >= 0.42. Given this conditions:

new_df=

```
|Column 1|Column 2|Column 3|
|   A    | 0.578  |   13   |
|   A    | 0.596  |   12   |
|   B    | 0.672  |   33   |
```

As you can see, I always use the same two columns to filter (2 and 3), with different conditions. I'm having problems wrapping my head around this. Is here where I should use the 'or' (|) operator?

Something like this:

```
new_df = df[(df['Column 1'] == 'A') & (df['Column 2'] >= 0.56) | 
        (df['Column 1'] == 'B') & (df['Column 2'] >= 0.38) | 
        (df['Column 1'] == 'C') & (df['Column 2'] >= 0.422]
```

Is this a good way to approach this problem with 'big' dataframes (around 10k rows)? Is this how it should be done?

Comment: Yes, that's a good way of doing it and your example is correct (exception made for "Column 3" that should be "Column 1" but it think it's just a typo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's one easy way to do that, for this reason, I would suggest you do the following :

- **Conditions**

```
case1=df[(df['Column 1'] == 'A') & (df['Column 2'] >= 0.56)]
case2=df[(df['Column 1'] == 'B') & (df['Column 2'] >= 0.38)]
case3=df[(df['Column 1'] == 'C') & (df['Column 2'] >= 0.422)]

# Now you can concat all the cases

new_df=pd.concat([case1,case2,case3],ignore_index=True)
```

- **Ouput**

```
    Column 1    Column 2    Column 3
0      A         0.578         13
1      A         0.596         12
2      B         0.672         33
```